# CSS - border not going over elements that float left

Tags: html, css

I have this code here:

```
<div style="border:3px solid #808080;">
    <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 38px;color: #808080;text-align: center;">Lowell</h1>
    <div class="column-1">
         <img src="images/ruler-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
         <img src="images/bed-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
         <img src="images/bath-icon.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

my problem is that the border does not go over the column-1, column-2, column-3...those elements are floating left, how do I get them to be included in the border?

Here is the CSS

```
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3
{
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    border-right: 3px solid #808080;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Use clearfix to the parent element. Here is the reference of clearfix https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either add a div in parent with `clear:both` property right after the floated divs as mentioned by RemyaJ. like this

https://jsfiddle.net/zmasvt8b/

Or

Simply give `overflow:hidden` property to the parent div. Like this

https://jsfiddle.net/jv5xtLg9/

Comment: I think you need to adjust the width of the elements. When margins and padding are added 33% is no longer a third.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you've already chosen an answer, but here is an alternative - using flexbox. I also separated all the CSS from the HTML (like it should be!)

```css
.container {
  /* Important for columns */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  /* Important for columns */
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  border-top: none;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
  border: 3px solid #808080;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Remove duplicate borders */
.item-2 {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Lowell</h1>
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item-1">
    <img src="images/ruler-icon.png">
  </div>

  <div class="item item-2">
    <img src="images/bed-icon.png">
  </div>

  <div class="item item-3">
    <img src="images/bath-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div with style clear:both after the floated divs inside parent div. This will hopefully fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that parent elements are never to contain floated elements. To make this happen, just add `overflow:auto;` to your main div. That will [force the div to contain floated elements that "overflow" the container](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#propdef-overflow).

[There are other, probably better ways to accomplish the same thing](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) but this is the easiest.

Never, ever add HTML elements to do what CSS can and should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the css you need. Choose the width according to your needs.

```
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3
{
    width: 30%;
    border-right: 3px solid #808080;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```